# Not Getting Link Response Headers in GitHub Pagination For Issues

Tags: github-api

I'm writing a quick python app to get stats on my public GitHub project.

When I call (https://api.github.com/repos/user/project/pulls), I get back some json, but because my project has more than 30 outstanding PRs, I get a Link response header with the next and last URLs for me to go call to get all PRs.

However, when I perform a parallel query for issues with a certain label (https://api.github.com/repos/user/project/issues?labels=label&status=opened), I only get 30 back (the pagination limit), but my response header doesn't have a next Link in it for me to follow.  I know my project has more than 30 issues that match that label.

Is this a bug in the GitHub API, or in what I'm doing?  Alternatively, I don't actually care about the issues themselves, just the count of issues with that label, so is there another way to just query for the count?

Comment: Yeah, that's a problem with the GitHub API -- I've opened an internal issue to investigate this and we'll follow up here as soon as there's any news. Sorry for the trouble!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  It'd be great if you could let me know if/when it's fixed.

Comment: Sure thing -- we'll let you know.

Comment: This should be fixed now -- please let me know if you can still reproduce the problem or if you notice any other problems.

Comment: Thanks!  I confirmed it's working for me now.

Comment: Passing page=1 get pram only returns Link header